# Spring Rest URL /rest/v1 is beeing added

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-hateoas

I am working on a existing project where the restControllers has a restmapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/test")`. There is **no** base URL added. I have checked all the option where the baseURL gets added but i dont find any in my application. When i run my server. The way to access is `<hostname>/rest/v1/test`.Application also uses Spring Hateoas. Can you let me know from where/how do these additional `/rest/v1` is getting added?

Answer (score 0):

You should find it configured in `web.xml` or some spring `config xml` where the servlet mapping url is done.

Comment: I am using webAppIntializer and have not set basepath URL anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If the project is generated using maven then you should see the application name in `pom.xml` file something like this.

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest</name>
```

and also check `web.xml` file inside `webappp/WEB-INF` directory or any other XML config file if you have.

Answer (score 0):

someone configure it somewhere. search for it in:

- application.properties

  - `server.servlet-path` = or `spring.data.rest.basePath` =
- Configuration file: just like @Arnad said
- Configuration Classes: search for a bean named RepositoryRestConfigurer
- search in whole project:

  - in eclipse use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> -> File search
  - in intellij: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

ref link : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have one of these property set in the `application.properties` file:

```
server.contextPath=/rest/v1
```

or

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/rest/v1
```

You can control the base path of you application from there.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

With very minimal code that you have added, I can only tell you possible place where the base url might have been configured.

1. On top of your `@RestController` annotated class.
2. In case of WebApplicationInitializer it must have been added on `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` something like below:

   ```
   ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container
         .addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));

   dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
   dispatcher.addMapping("/rest/v1/");
   ```